# How to trim the decimal part from money field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View() with a link to make a payment. Link looks something like this

```
<a href="/paynow?id=@(Model.Id)&Amt=@(Model.Amount)">Pay Now</a>
```

My problem is Model.Amount has the amount format like this  20.00 or 100.00 because the DataType is money and its adding extra zero's.

I need to remove the '.' so it reads 2000 or 10000.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you please describe the programming and templates language you use a bit more?  From your example it is not obvious

Comment: There is no data type Money in C# as far as I know assuming you are using C#. Do you maybe mean Decimal?

Comment: You can use one of the [standard number formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g. `Model.Amount.ToString("F0")`.